# Android dev - TextView won't show up

Tags: java, android

I just started experimenting with Android app development and so I decided to give Android's own tutorials a go (this one: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html )

The textview in my new activity just won't show. Here's my code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Get the intent and the message sent with it */
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(GoogleTutActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        /* Create a new textview where we can show the message the user sent */
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your TextView to your XML file, then create its object in onCreate and use it.

Comment: and first of all using components of XML use setContentView(xyz); It is normally putted after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't add the textview to layout.
1.    `setContentView(textView);`
2. or add textview to the xml activity_display_message and set id.
then

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
 textView.setTextSize(40);
 textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just did this tutorial as a refresher and ran into this same problem. The tutorial does not explicitly state to delete the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)`, so I ended up having two calls to `setContentView()`. That's not allowed.

Two solutions will work. **The easiest way** to make this demo work is to delete the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)` line. Then the activity will have only one `setContentView()`, i.e. `setContentView(textView)` declared at the end of `onCreate`. That will use the programatic TextView a few lines above it.

**A better solution** is to create a layout for this activity in the res/layout folder and put the `TextView` details there rather than in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  You would expect the docs on the actual android site to get it right.  Having a flawed introductory tutorial is one of the quickest ways to turn a newbie off from learning to code for any given platform.